# Failing to do a GET request after login

Tags: c#, api, automation, restsharp

Im very new to RestSharp and have been struggling with this for the last few days but the jist of it is I need to do a POST with a username and password, and obtain a bearer token to login to complete a series of requests.
For this particular test its a GET to obtain a list of users.

Here is my code

```
 public void Authorization()
        {
            var client = new RestClient("https://url");
            var request = new RestRequest("api/auth/account/Login", Method.POST);

            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            request.AddJsonBody(new { password = "TestPassword123!", username = "testuser@email.com" });
            var response = client.ExecutePostAsync(request).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            var bearerToken = response.Content;
            var jwtAuth = new JwtAuthenticator(bearerToken);
            client.Authenticator = jwtAuth;

            var request2 = new RestRequest("/api/auth/Users", Method.GET);


            var response2 = client.ExecuteAsync(request2).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            Console.WriteLine(response2.Content);
            Console.WriteLine(response2.ErrorException);
            Console.WriteLine(response2.ErrorMessage);
            Console.WriteLine(response2.Headers);
            Console.WriteLine(response2.IsSuccessful);
            Console.WriteLine(response2.StatusCode);
           
        }
```

I guess the problem im having is with Authentication and logging?.. when I run this my output is as follows

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[RestSharp.Parameter]
False
Unauthorized
```

The thing im confused about is when i print the bearerToken variable to the console its clearly my bearerToken in string format, what else would I need to do in order for the GET request following the post to go through?

Here is the postman screenshot of the GET request
[image: postman]

Here is the postman screenshot of the POST request
[image: postman post request]

Answer (score 0):

While the code is running, have you tried to inspect the requests to see if the meta-data is correct and if Bearer Token is being added correctly? To do so, you can use a Debugging Proxy like https://www.telerik.com/fiddler

**Update**:I noticed you have a forward-slash ("/api") in your *request2* endpoint string `new RestRequest("/api/auth/Users", Method.GET);` - see if taking that out makes a difference? In your first request, you dont have a slash

**Update 2**: I **think** I've figured it out! Try calling the `Authenticate()` method from `JwtAuthenticator`, so your code should look like:

```
var jwtAuth = new JwtAuthenticator(token);
jwt.Authenticate(client, request);
var request2 = new RestRequest("/api/auth/Users", Method.GET);
```

I found this out by looking at the JwtAuthenticator object - looks like it updates the Http Header for Authorization.

I can't immediately see what the issue is, someone else might, hope this helps

Comment: Good eye, i took out the slash and I still got the same console output unfortunately.

Comment: @getCritical see my 'update 2' above - hope this helps! If solved, please mark this as the answer :)

Comment: Didnt seem to work unfortunately, getting the same error saying unauthorized

Comment: I assume you've debugged it the code, but if you haven't inspected the request Postman is making you could use Telerik Fiddler to look at the request meta-data (headers etc) and compare that to what your code is doing. Ignore me if you've done this

Comment: I was using the debugger in visual studio and I believe I got lucky but  when I removed this line         ``` //   client.Authenticator = new JwtAuthenticator("Bearer " + bearerToken); ``` and just sent the bearer with the header and it worked\

Comment: Nice one! I'm still a bit confused, and I did think about that way of adding it in the ehader, but I didn't think it was necessary since you were using JwtAuthenticator - probs used in the wrong way. Dangit, wont get an answer this time!